# Unit testing AWS SNS Publishing message

Tags: java, junit, mocking, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I'm wondering how can I test a method like this:

```
public PublishResponse broadcast(String eventJson, Class<? extends BaseEvent> type) {
    //Build Sns client.
    AwsCredentials awsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials
            .create(snsConfiguration.getAwsAccessKeyId(), snsConfiguration.getAwsSecretAccessKey());
    StaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials);
    SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient.builder().credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
    //Prepare message attributes.
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> messageAttributes = new HashMap<>();
    MessageAttributeValue messageAttributeValue = MessageAttributeValue.builder().dataType("String").stringValue(type.getName())
            .build();
    messageAttributes.put("type", messageAttributeValue);
    //Publish message with event json to Amazon SNS.
    return snsClient.publish(PublishRequest.builder()
            .message(eventJson)
            .messageAttributes(messageAttributes)
            .topicArn(snsConfiguration.getTopicARN())
            .build());
}
```

All the code here depend on AWS SDK api. I know that I could some moking here but at the end time his method's responsibility is to send a message to SNS. How to write united  testing for such thing?

Comment: For integration testing, take a look at this: https://github.com/localstack/localstack